# Problems with cvWaitKey() in multithreading

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, opencv, gstreamer

I have an eclipse project (linux), in which I am using 3 threads. First thread used to pump video using `libusb_bulk_transfer` (`libusb1.0` library). 
The second thread is used to convert the video into jpg and sending it to the udp port using `gstreamer1.6.3`. The last and main thread is used to transform a raw matrix data into `i420` formate. 
Everything works fine, but then in the main function I am trying to use `cvWaitKey(30)` function of `opencv-3.1.0`, my main thread stops and dies on this function. `Valgrind` gave no results. Here is a part of the code, which causes problems.

```
pthread_t tid1;
pthread_t tid2;
pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, reader, NULL);
pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, reader2, NULL);

CvMat mat;

cvNamedWindow("src2", 1);

while(1)
{

    if(cc==1)
    {

        buf2textures();
        cvCopy(I420Frame,leftFrameForShow2);
        mtx.lock();
        m=cvarrToMat(leftFrameForShow2);
        mtx.unlock();
        cvShowImage("src2",leftFrameForShow2);

    }

    char c = cvWaitKey(30);

    if (c == 27)
    {

        break;

    }

}

cyusb_close();
printf("EXIT");
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: Do you have a HighGUI window as part of your code? The documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html) clearly states the following:

`Note: The function only works if there is at least one HighGUI window created and the window is active. If there are several HighGUI windows, any of them can be active.`

Comment: Yes. cvNamedWindow("src2", 1) function create HighGUI window. I didnt mention, that it work nice, if I didnt use thread with gstreamer.

Comment: Oops. Missed that when I looked over the code block.

Comment: Are you calling all three functions (`cvNamedWindow`, `cvShowImage` and `cvWaitKey`) only from the main thread? Everything else is not supported as far as I remember.

Comment: Yes. I called it only from main thread.